# Python 3 - How do you re-create your Pipfile?

Tags: python-3.x, pipfile

I am a major Python noob, and I made the mistake of manually deleting my Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, thinking that they would eventually regenerate.

How can I re-create these files?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix to this:

First you need to install pipenv if you haven't already:

```
pip install pipenv
```

Then change directory to the folder containing your Python project and initiate Pipenv (replace my_project with the name of your project folder):

```
cd my_project
pipenv install
```

This will create two new files, Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, in your project directory, and a new virtual environment for your project if it doesn’t exist already.

Comment: Or, you may not have deleted it permenantly in which case you could restore it from the recycle bin

Comment: Or, if that doesn't work, you could always try completely re-installing python

Answer (score 1):

For regular pip:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

For pipenv:

`pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt`

And to install:

`pip install requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Situation: you have deleted Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, but your pipenv environment is still there. By this I mean `pipenv shell` puts you in your environment with a python that has all your packages right there.

```
# Create a new Pipfile
pipenv install

# Get a list of your packages + version from the would-be "reqiurements.txt", then install them one by one.
pipenv run pip freeze|sed 's/^/pipenv install /'|source /dev/stdin
```

Note that this is not a perfect solution, as it will specify the versions in the production target environment as you would get from `pip freeze` i.e. `requirements.txt`. However this has saved me more than once, so I hope it helps you.

Comment: Note: you need run the commands from the directory where the Pipfiles were.

Comment: Ah, have just realised that this is almost identical to the answer from @DUDANF, with the only benefit that you don't need to create the requirements.txt file. NVM